# Slow working converting DataFrame to dict

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I am doing batching process. From dataset like:

**data** =

```
[
        '{"CustomerId": "f796bce5-f416-502c-a1c5-6e7c57a3676d", "Email": "fname@emailreaction.com", "FirstName": "fname", "Surname": "lname", "DateOfBirth": "1970-02-01"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "f796bce5-f416-502c-a1c5-6e7c57a3676d", "Email": "business@emailreaction.org", "FirstName": "Lan-lor", "Surname": "Lord-Smith", "DateOfBirth": "1966-02-16"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "BBB-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d", "Email": "second@gmail.com", "FirstName": "Mark", "Surname": "Spenser", "DateOfBirth": "1987-09-20"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "EEE-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d", "Email": "fifth@gmail.com", "FirstName": "Bob", "Surname": "Lein", "DateOfBirth": "1986-10-21"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "BBB-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d", "Email": "landlord@emailreaction.org", "FirstName": "Lan-lor", "Surname": "Lord-Smith", "DateOfBirth": "1966-02-16"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "AAA-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d", "Email": "first@gmail.com", "FirstName": "Steve", "Surname": "Jobs", "DateOfBirth": "1985-08-21"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "AAA-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d", "Email": "third@gmail.com", "FirstName": "Jeniffer", "Surname": "Sue", "DateOfBirth": "1981-07-21"}',
        '{"CustomerId": "DDD-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d", "Email": "fourth@gmail.com", "FirstName": "Tim", "Surname": "Rob", "DateOfBirth": "1979-12-17"}'
......
about 1 million rows
......
]
```

For batching  I am using `.groupby()` into pandas.
Then need to converto from DataFrame to dict and very slow working `.to_dict()`. In my function it is: 
`result = [pd.DataFrame.to_dict(group, orient="records") for name, group in group_by]`

What is the problem?

```
def get_batched_list_by_id(data, batch_by="CustomerId"):
    group_by = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(i) for i in data]).groupby(batch_by)
    result = [pd.DataFrame.to_dict(group, orient="records") for name, group in group_by]
    return result
```

I am expecting the result:

```
[
 [{'CustomerId': 'AAA-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'DateOfBirth': '1985-08-21', 'Email': 'first@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Steve', 'Surname': 'Jobs'}, {'CustomerId': 'AAA-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'DateOfBirth': '1981-07-21', 'Email': 'third@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Jeniffer', 'Surname': 'Sue'}],
 [{'CustomerId': 'BBB-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'DateOfBirth': '1987-09-20', 'Email': 'second@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Mark', 'Surname': 'Spenser'}, {'CustomerId': 'BBB-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'DateOfBirth': '1966-02-16', 'Email': 'landlord@emailreaction.org', 'FirstName': 'Lan-lor', 'Surname': 'Lord-Smith'}],
 [{'CustomerId': 'DDD-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'DateOfBirth': '1979-12-17', 'Email': 'fourth@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Tim', 'Surname': 'Rob'}], 
 [{'CustomerId': 'EEE-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'DateOfBirth': '1986-10-21', 'Email': 'fifth@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Lein'}], 
 [{'CustomerId': 'f796bce5-f416-502c-a1c5-6e7c57a3676d', 'DateOfBirth': '1970-02-01', 'Email': 'fname@emailreaction.com', 'FirstName': 'fname', 'Surname': 'lname'}, {'CustomerId': 'f796bce5-f416-502c-a1c5-6e7c57a3676d', 'DateOfBirth': '1966-02-16', 'Email': 'business@emailreaction.org', 'FirstName': 'Lan-lor', 'Surname': 'Lord-Smith'}] 
....about 1 million....
]
```

And I got it, but the function was worked about 30minut

Comment: You're not actually doing any batching. You're loading each element of the list one-by-one, and parsing it as a JSON. How are you getting this data into your Python process?

Comment: I am getting this format from DB and then try to group it by `CustomerId`. Resulting format needed for me. I am grouping data into pair and then provide result like list of grouped by `CustomerId` lists. Then the result I am pushing to Kafka. Each grouped lists from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pandas for so simple a groupby:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_batched_list_by_id_no_pandas(data, batch_by="CustomerId"):
    dicts = json.loads("[" +', '.join(data) + "]")
    # Create a defaultdict of lists
    temp = defaultdict(list)
    for _dict in dicts:
        # Put each sub dict into temp keyed by `batch_by`
        temp[_dict[batch_by]] += [_dict]
    return list(temp.values())
```

Comparing the timings of this function to your function (for only the sample you've shown):

`%timeit get_batched_list_by_id(data)`: `3.85 ms ± 48.8 µs per loop`

`%timeit get_batched_list_by_id_no_pandas(data)`: `13.9 µs ± 60.7 ns`

A savings of nearly 300x. So your job that ran in 30min should run in approximately 7 seconds.

Comment: input list `data` needs to group by `CustomerId`. For this, I am using `pandas`. Check the expecting result into description.

Comment: @VasiliSeniuts I've updated the answer to conform to your request.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! Works well for me. Why was the performance issue with `pandas`?

Comment: @Cherny The performance wasn't necessarily with `pandas` *per se*. The main issue is that you are going back and forth between different object types. Parsing the JSON strings into pandas DataFrames takes processing. Sending the dataframes back to dictionaries takes processing. Your biggest performance hit, though is actually probably due to the fact that you're calling `json.loads` millions of times (i.e. for each record) in your list comprehension, whereas the function I provided only calls it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.to_dict("record")

df1.groupby('CustomerId').apply(function1).tolist()
```

out:

```
[[{'CustomerId': 'AAA-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'Email': 'first@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Steve', 'Surname': 'Jobs', 'DateOfBirth': '1985-08-21'}, {'CustomerId': 'AAA-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'Email': 'third@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Jeniffer', 'Surname': 'Sue', 'DateOfBirth': '1981-07-21'}], [{'CustomerId': 'BBB-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'Email': 'second@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Mark', 'Surname': 'Spenser', 'DateOfBirth': '1987-09-20'}, {'CustomerId': 'BBB-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'Email': 'landlord@emailreaction.org', 'FirstName': 'Lan-lor', 'Surname': 'Lord-Smith', 'DateOfBirth': '1966-02-16'}], [{'CustomerId': 'DDD-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'Email': 'fourth@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Tim', 'Surname': 'Rob', 'DateOfBirth': '1979-12-17'}], [{'CustomerId': 'EEE-6571-589b-8b6e-dd4f6d', 'Email': 'fifth@gmail.com', 'FirstName': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Lein', 'DateOfBirth': '1986-10-21'}], [{'CustomerId': 'f796bce5-f416-502c-a1c5-6e7c57a3676d', 'Email': 'fname@emailreaction.com', 'FirstName': 'fname', 'Surname': 'lname', 'DateOfBirth': '1970-02-01'}, {'CustomerId': 'f796bce5-f416-502c-a1c5-6e7c57a3676d', 'Email': 'business@emailreaction.org', 'FirstName': 'Lan-lor', 'Surname': 'Lord-Smith', 'DateOfBirth': '1966-02-16'}]]
```